# How do I bind a ComboBox so the displaymember is concat of 2 fields of source datatable?

Tags: c#, data-binding, combobox

I'd like to bind a `ComboBox` to a `DataTable` (I cannot alter its original schema)

```
cbo.DataSource = tbldata;
cbo.DataTextField = "Name";
cbo.DataValueField = "GUID";
cbo.DataBind();
```

I want the `ComboBox` show `tbldata.Name + tbldata.Surname`.

Of course adding the new name+surname as a field to the `tbldata` just before binding is possible, but I am hoping for a more elegant solution along the lines of (pseudocode)

```
cbo.DataTextField = "Name";
cbo.DataTextField += "Surname";
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The calculated column solution is probably the best one. But if you can't alter the data table's schema to add that, you can loop through the table and populate a new collection that will serve as the data source.

```
var dict = new Dictionary<Guid, string>();
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    dict.Add(row["GUID"], row["Name"] + " " + row["Surname"]);
}
cbo.DataSource = dict;
cbo.DataTextField = "Value";
cbo.DataValueField = "Key";
cbo.DataBind();
```

Obviously this isn't as performant as binding directly to the DataTable but I wouldn't worry about that unless the table has thousands of rows.

Answer (score 19):

The easiest way is to create a new calculated column in the DataTable, using the Expression property :

```
tbldata.Columns.Add("FullName", typeof(string), "Name + ' ' + Surname");
...
cbo.DataTextField = "FullName";
```

Comment: I like this a lot better than the suggestions people keep making about modifying the data object and creating a new property.

Answer (score 5):

I would create a property on your data object then map that to the DataTextField

**Data Object**

```
public string FullName
{
  get { return Name + " " + Surname; }
}
```

**Code-behind**

```
cbo.DataSource = tbldata;
cbo.DataTextField = "FullName";
cbo.DataValueField = "GUID";
cbo.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 5):

Or implement 'Format' event like this:

```
DataRow r = ((DataRowView)e.ListItem).Row;
e.Value = r[ "FirstName" ] + " - " + r[ "LastName" ];
```

Comment: Most useful ! Thanks.

Comment: Where is the Format event?

Comment: @TangMonk, the Format event is in the ComboBox class.  See here: [ComboBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 2):

Have a property in your class that is the concat of Name and Surname. And bind the DataTextField to this property.

In case you are binding it to a DataTable, you can add a new column to the DataTable whose values are concat of Name and Surname and bind it to the combo.

Comment: i agree, can't think of another way

Comment: Since this is a simple one-use only, using a class as a base for this is overkill.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at calculated columns using the [Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx) property of DataColumn.

Answer (score 0):

You can register the combo binding event and iterate the items, setting each item text to the desired fields using the combobox item data item.