# How to add 2 column in combobox?

Tags: c#, winforms, ado.net, combobox

I think for displaying columns in combobox is responsible this string in Desingner of Form:

```
this.ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "name";
```

But, i cant add anything near "name", combobox shows in all strings : `System.Data.DataRowView`

Maybe its wrong, tell me please how do this?

I'm just drag table as combobox from Data Source:

When Form Loading:

```
private void frmCheck_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
 this.ttzTableAdapter.Fill(this.dbDataSet.ttz, Convert.ToInt32(idFromWork.Text));
}
```

So combobox show, just "name" in list, i want that he show "number" and "name" in list.

```
"Convert.ToInt32(idFromWork.Text)"
```

parameter for show names where id_ttz(ID) = @idwork

Comment: Please show the code where you build your datasource and how you connect it to the combobox1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DisplayMember` is [a string specifying the name of an object property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember.aspx) that is contained in the collection specified by the DataSource property. You cannot specify several properties to display. If you'll try to do this, your 'compound property' will not be found, and objects will be displayed via `ToString()` implementation (thats why you see `System.Data.DataRowView` string).

If you need to display several properties of object, you can [create custom multi-column combobox](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3206/Multi-Column-ComboBox) and implement it's pop-up as ListView or DataGridView.

UPDATE: Instead of binding directly to DataTable of DataView, you can create your own anonymous type, which will provide formatted text for displaying:

```
ComboBox1.DataSource = tdbDataSet.ttz.AsEnumerable()
          .Select(row => new 
               { 
                 Text = String.Format("{0,5} | {1}", row["id_ttz"], row["name"]),
                 Value = row["id_ttz"]
               })
         .ToList();

ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Text";
ComboBox1.ValueMember = "Value";
```

Comment: @Johnny write this where you assign datasource to your combobox

Comment: what is responsible of distance between rows?

Comment: @Johnny `{0,5}` says that first argument (id) should take at least five symbols (adds spaces at the beginning of string). Also you are free to change string format.

Comment: @Johnny looks like you didn't provide minimum length for argument in second case. See string formatting examples here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fht0f5be.aspx

Comment: All ok, but now i cant correct add rows in the table, cause parameter get value from combobox like a: 
combobox1.Text, this is number+name in 1 column, but i need in separate. I'm try use two textbox with bindingsource, when Form loading tb's get values, but when i change new double combobox, nothing...

Answer (score 2):

You can not add two column in combobox. how ever you can concat values from two object. see this [WinForms combobox with multiple columns (C#)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091414/winforms-combobox-with-multiple-columns-c)

Answer (score 1):

In your query add a calculated column

```
  select name, ..., name+' '+number as colToDisplay...
```

and use it like this

```
   this.ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "colToDisplay";
```

Or if you are binding your combo  to a `custom object`

add a new Property that combines the columns you need to display

```
 public string PropertyToShow
 {
   get{return name+" "+otherProp;}
 }
```

Comment: I think he is binding combobox to the DataView object.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky So i think modifing the `sql query` will work for him.

Comment: Yes, this is also option. But modifying SQL because of displaying data in some control.. overkill :)

Answer (score 0):

You have several possibilities. If you don't specify a `DisplayMember`, the combo box uses the `ToString` method to get a string. So one option is naturally to override the `ToString` method of your class, if you are under control of it. Or you could add a property returning an appropriate string and use this in `DisplayMember`.

A completely different approach is to create your own combo box by deriving one from `ComboBox`. Then change the `DrawMode` of your combo box to `OwnerDrawFixed` if the items have all the same height or `OwnerDrawVariable` if they might have different heights. You will have to override `OnDrawItem` and do your own drawing logic. If you specified `OwnerDrawVariable` you must override `OnMeasureItem` as well in order to tell the combo box height of each item.

Using this second approach enables you to create real columns and to draw a vertical separator and much more. You can draw icons use different background and text colors, different fonts etc.

Comment: I think he is binding combobox to the DataView object. So, overriding ToString or creating custom property is not an option.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky: I never worked with `DataView` objects. Would it be possible to add a calculated column? This would be comparable to adding a property.

Comment: Olivier, sorry, but I either don't know if expression columns available for DataView