# ComboBox with two columns in C#

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WinForms combobox with multiple columns (C#)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091414/winforms-combobox-with-multiple-columns-c)

I this procedure 
ALTER proc [dbo].[VCNAE]
as
select cnae_id,cnae_descricao, cnae_classe    from tbl_CNAE order by cnae_descricao

I use for populate this dataset

```
        SqlCommand llena4 = new SqlCommand("vcnae", abre);
        llena4.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        da2.SelectCommand = llena4;
        da2.Fill(carga1, "cnae");//4
```

Then i populate  combobox

```
         BindingSource srd = new BindingSource();
         srd.DataSource = llenar.Tables["cnae"];
         CmbCnaePrin.DataSource = srd;
         CmbCnaePrin.DisplayMember = "cnae_descricao" ;
         CmbCnaePrin.ValueMember = "cnae_id";
         CmbCnaePrin.SelectedValue = 259;
```

I want to show in display member this :

cnae_descricao, cnae_classe

```
                     displaymember = "cnae_descricao"+"cnae_classe"; but this code not work how can  i solve this::????
```

Thanks

Comment: I am assuming that you are using Win Forms. Do you what you want you have to concatenate the string at SQL level. Example: Select cnae_descricao + ' ' + cnae_classe As cnae_fulldesc From tb_data

Comment: Thanks I have solve this ALTER proc [dbo].[VCNAE]
as
select cnae_id, cnae_descricao + '  ' + cnae_classe as cnaetotal  from tbl_cnae 
order by cnae_descricao