# Display multiple fields in combobox

Tags: c#, sql, .net, winforms, combobox

I'm using c# 2010 , I want to display combo-box list on search like this :
[image]

In my case, I have a table "Client", is there any way to set Display-Member which contains three fields of "Client" : FirstName, LastName, City as shown in the image above?

Comment: Winforms? ASP .net? Please tag the question accordingly. Your question is valid, but I don't know how to answer it without knowing more context. EDIT: `.net` still doesn't clarify much I'm afraid. Tag again.

Comment: Thanks for remark, I've updated it

Comment: I'm going to assume this is winforms, as ASP .net would term it 'DropDownList' instead, but it could still easily be misinterpreted.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/1091414/1271037, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/982498, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19781/A-data-bound-multi-column-combobox, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3206/Multi-Column-ComboBox, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3513/Multi-Column-ComboBox

Comment: Maybe you can to add additional column in your dtatsource, that will combine all data you need, and set it as DisplayMember?

Comment: @Lev I've already done what, but the problem is the combobox searches only from the beginning, e.g : if you have an item like this :
Text1 | Text2 | Word, and you type 'word', no result !

Comment: You talking about autoComplete?

Comment: No, my problem is not how to set display member which contains three fields, but how to search any word in item.
e.g : if we have : 
item1=" text1 text2 word word";
item2=" aaa bbb ccc ";
so when you type cc, you won't get any result !

Comment: This is tagged with sql. Can you include the sql query that you are using?

Answer (score 0):

So no one helped me, thanks all for comments, in fact I found a solution : I set a panel located under Combobox, contains a Datagridview assigned to Client DataSource, I play with hide/show and Combobox_textChanged :)