# How to add item to a comboBox in Visual Basic with modifying the attribute .Value

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I have a little problem with my code in Visual Basic. It is quite simple but I'm very new to this language.

In Visual Basic, I want to add new items in my combo box like this:

```
ComboBox1.Items.Add(array(1))
```

When the program executes the code, I suppose that I make a new `ComboBox` item in a specific position with the attribute `.Text`, but I want to access and add some data in the attribute `.Value` at the same time. The code is inside a loop.

My Code:

```
While src.Peek() <> -1
    cadena = src.ReadLine()
    intermitja = Split(cadena, "/")
    ComboBox1.Items.Add(intermitja(1))
    ' I tried this...
    ' ComboBox1.Items(ComboBox1.Items.Count).value = (intermitja(0))
End While
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear, but it sounds like you need to look at DataBinding and use `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember` to show one thing but return another to your code.  There are gobs of examples here.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: It seems to me from `Split()` you want a `ComboBox` with multiple columns. Normally only one item per item per line is possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WinForms combobox with multiple columns (C#)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091414/winforms-combobox-with-multiple-columns-c)

Comment: Agreed with the question not being clear: you don't make a combobox item by handling the `Text` Property.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone and my teacher I have already been able to do what I wanted @plutonix told me the answer despite my unclear question, thank you very much.

I needed something like this:

> ```
>     ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Text"
>     ComboBox1.ValueMember = "Value"
>     Dim tb As New DataTable
>     tb.Columns.Add("Text", GetType(String))
>     tb.Columns.Add("Value", GetType(Integer))
>     tb.Rows.Add("USA", 101)
>     tb.Rows.Add("UK", 109)
>     tb.Rows.Add("France", 106)
>     tb.Rows.Add("Germany", 121)
>     ComboBox1.DataSource = tb
> ```