# Add 2 or more field to value member of C# coding

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, dataset, valuemember

I have table with 4 primary key fields. I load that in to drop down list in my WinForm application created by using C#.

On the TextChanged event of drop down list I have certain TextBox and I want to fill the information recived by the table for the certain field I selected by the drop down list.

So as I say the table having 4 fields. Can I get those all 4 fields into **value member** from the data set, or could you please tell me whether is that not possible?

Thank you.

`Datatable dt=dba.getName(); 
cmb_name.ValueMember="id"; 
cmb_name.DisplayMember="name"; 
cmb_name.DataSource=dt;`

this is normal format.. but i have more key fields.. so i need to add more key fields..

Comment: What does your code look like that is populating the drop down list?

Comment: ... and when you're already highlighting the **value member** you could also ensure that there is a property like that in the [`DataSet` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.aspx)(what's not the case). Otherwise you need to explain what *you* mean by this.

Comment: Datatable dt=dba.getName(); cmb_name.ValueMember="id"; cmb_name.DisplayMember="name"; cmb_name.DataSource=dt; this is normal format.. but i have more key fields.. so i need to add more key fields..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [DataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w67sdsex.aspx) property to bind your source data to the ComboBox (e.g. a List of Entities, or a DataTable, etc), and then set the `DisplayMember` property of the ComboBox to the (string) name of the field you want to display.

After the user has selected an Item, you can then cast the `SelectedItem` back to the original  row data type (Entity, DataRow, etc - it will still be the same type as you put in), and then you can retrieve your 4 composite keys to the original item.

This way you avoid the `SelectedValue` problem entirely.

**Edit**:

Populate as follows:

```
cmb_name.DisplayMember = "name";
cmb_name.DataSource = dt;

// Ignore ValueMember and Selected Value entirely
```

When you want to retrieve the selected item

```
var selectedRow = (cmb_name.SelectedItem as DataRowView );
```

Now you can retrieve the 4 values of your PK, e.g. `selectedRow["field1"], selectedRow["field2"], selectedRow["field3"] etc`

If however you mean that you want to **DISPLAY** 4 columns to the user (i.e. nothing to do with your Table Key), then see here [How do I bind a ComboBox so the displaymember is concat of 2 fields of source datatable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006521/how-do-i-bind-a-combo-so-the-displaymember-is-concat-of-2-fields-of-source-datat)

Comment: Datatable dt=dba.getName(); cmb_name.ValueMember="id"; cmb_name.DisplayMember="name"; cmb_name.DataSource=dt; this is normal format.. but i have more key fields.. so i need to add more key fields..

Answer (score 1):

```
cmb_name.DisplayMember = "name";
cmb_name.DataSource = dt;
DataRowView selectedRow = (cmb_name.SelectedItem as DataRowView );
```

The result will be here:

```
MessageBox.Show(selectedRow.Row[0].ToString());
MessageBox.Show(selectedRow.Row[1].ToString());
MessageBox.Show(selectedRow.Row[2].ToString());
MessageBox.Show(selectedRow.Row[3].ToString());
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get some data from a ComboBox in to a `List` you can use something like this

```
List<string> ListOfComboData = new List<string>();
ListOfComboData = yourComboBox.Items.OfType<string>().ToList<string>();
```

I have no real idea if this is what you mean as the question is very poorly structured. I hope this helps...

Edit: To put the selected text in to some `TextBox` use

```
yourTextBox.Text = youComboBox.Text;
```

in the `SelectedIndexChanged` event of your `ComboBox`.

Answer (score 0):

You could follow the approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3063421/232566) with the following class:

```
public class ComboBoxItem
{
   public string Text { get; set; }
   public object[] PrimaryKey { get; set; }
}

private void Test()
{
    ComboboxItem item = new ComboboxItem();
    item.Text = "Item text1";
    item.PrimaryKey = new object[] { primaryKey1, primaryKey2, primaryKey3, primaryKey4};

    comboBox1.Items.Add(item);

    comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;

    MessageBox.Show((comboBox1.SelectedItem as ComboboxItem).Value.ToString());
}
```