# How to append two field values in combobox display member in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

In my table, I have a field of `firstname` and `lastname`, now what I want is to set `firstname` and `lastname` as `displaymember` in a combobox, but I don't know how to do it.

Something like this

```
cmbEmployees.DataSource = GetEmployees();
//something like below line which doesn't work
cmbEmployees.DisplayMember = "lastname, first_name";     
cmbEmployees.ValueMember = "id";
```

How can I achieve this? So that both `lastname` and `firstname` will be displayed in the `combobox`

Comment: You could add a property that combines the two names.

Comment: By default the control will display what is returned by the ToString method, so you could override that.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Let's say you had a class like this:

```
class Person
{
    public string FirstName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string FullName
    {
        get
        {
            return LastName + ", " + FirstName;
        }
    }

    public Person(string firstname, string lastname)
    {
        FirstName = firstname;
        LastName = lastname;
    }
}
```

If you don't have a `FullName` property, just create one in the format you wish to display the name. Then set the `DisplayMember` equal to `FullName`.

Answer (score 64):

This example will guide you how to do that without modifying your base class.

First, you can leave your DisplayMember with one property, let's say:

```
cmbEmployees.DisplayMember = "lastname";
```

Now, go to your form in a [Design] mode,
right click on the ComboBox -> Properties.

In the top of the Properties window, click on Events (lightning icon),

look for Format in the events list below (under Property Changed) and type there some event name, let's say: ComboBoxFormat , and press Enter.  You will see this:

```
private void ComboBoxFormat(object sender, ListControlConvertEventArgs e)
{

}
```

And now write these following lines inside:

```
private void ComboBoxFormat(object sender, ListControlConvertEventArgs e)
{
    // Assuming your class called Employee , and Firstname & Lastname are the fields
    string lastname = ((Employee)e.ListItem).Firstname;
    string firstname = ((Employee)e.ListItem).Lastname;
    e.Value = lastname + " " + firstname;
}
```

That's it ;)

Comment: that's amazing solution

Comment: Very clean solution! Please note that it works fine even if the source class is NOT your. For example I need it for System.IO.SerialPort enumeration, now I don't need to create an "ad hoc" inherited class.

Comment: Eliran, can you explain how to set this ? Where did you get FirstName, I don't know what a field means in this case. I databind combobox using datatable and set Display and ValueMember based on what datatable column names are.

Answer (score 19):

Your query should be like this in **GetEmployees()** function.

```
"SELECT id,(lastname + ' ' + first_name) AS NAME FROM TABLE"

cmbEmployees.DataSource = GetEmployees();
cmbEmployees.DisplayMember = "NAME"; 
cmbEmployees.ValueMember = "id";
```

Answer (score 3):

in C# 6 create readonly property in your Employee class

```
public string FullName=>$"{lastname} {firstname}";
```

then

```
cmbEmployees.DataSource = GetEmployees();
//something like below line which doesn't work
cmbEmployees.DisplayMember = "FullName";     
cmbEmployees.ValueMember = "id";
```

Answer (score 2):

Try one of those approaches:

- new `Dictionary` with concatenated fields as value - https://stackoverflow.com/a/1006588/1816426
- calculated column - https://stackoverflow.com/a/1006546/1816426

Answer (score 0):

```
// Declare a class
private class ComboRec
   {
     public string ID { get; set; }
     public string FirstName { get; set; }
     public string LastName { get; set; }
     public string FullName { get; set; }
     public string Department { get; set; }
   }

   

    // Fill the Combo Items
    private void FillMyComboList()
            {
                EmployeesCombo.Items.Clear();
                EmployeesCombo.ValueMember = "ID";
                EmployeesCombo.DisplayMember = "FullName";
    
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select id, firstname, lastname, department from employees order by lastname, firstname", MyConnection);
                cmd.Transaction = myTransaction;
                MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    
                ComboRec comborec;
    
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    comborec = new ComboRec();
                    comborec.ID = rdr["id"].ToString();
                    comborec.FirstName = rdr["firstname"].ToString();
                    comborec.LastName = rdr["lastname"].ToString();
                    comborec.FullName = rdr["lastname"].ToString() + ", " + rdr["firstname"].ToString();
                    comborec.Department = rdr["department"].ToString();
    
                    EmployeesCombo.Items.Add(comborec);
                }
    
                rdr.Close();
            }   
       
       
    // Get the values from combo
    string id = ((ComboRec)EmployeesCombo.SelectedItem).ID);
    string firstname = ((ComboRec)EmployeesCombo.SelectedItem).FirstName);
    string lastname = ((ComboRec)EmployeesCombo.SelectedItem).LastName);
    string fullname = ((ComboRec)EmployeesCombo.SelectedItem).FullName);
    string department = ((ComboRec)EmployeesCombo.SelectedItem).Department);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void alldata1()
    {
        var Person= context.Person.Select(s => new { 
            display = s.surName+" "+s.name,
            value = s.studentID
        });
        comboBoxStudentNom.DataSource = Person.ToList();
        comboBoxStudentNom.ValueMember = "value";
        comboBoxStudentNom.DisplayMember = "display";
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

CREATE VIEW [dbo].[get_view]
    AS 
    SELECT CONCAT(sell_tb.Name,extra_tb.Name,purchase_tb.Name) AS Name FROM sell_tb FULL JOIN extra_tb ON extra_tb.E_ID = sell_tb.E_ID
    FULL JOIN purchase_tb ON purchase_tb.S_ID = sell_tb.S_ID;

```
      private void alldata1()
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from [get_view]";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        sda.Fill(dt);
        comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
        conn.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Please explain what your answer does.