# Combobox format displays tab in textbox, not in dropdown

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface, combobox

I have a `Province` object, with `ProvinceCode` and `ProvinceName` properties. I want to display both in a Visual Webgui (Winforms-based) combobox, with a tab between them.

I am using the PropertyChanged - Format event, as suggested by Eliran's answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14679253/how-to-append-two-field-values-in-combobox-display-member-in-c-sharp) question:

```
    private void Province_Format(object sender, ListControlConvertEventArgs e)
    {
        string provCode = ((Province)e.ListItem).ProvinceCode;
        string provName = ((Province)e.ListItem).ProvinceName;
        e.Value = provCode + "\t" + provName;
    }
```

When the combobox is rendered, the tab displays properly in the textbox area, but displays as a single space in the listbox area.

Does a Winforms combobox support tabs in its listbox area?

**Edit:** Now have enough reputation to add a picture.

[image: Combobox showing tab in textbox, space in listarea]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way to achieve this, if your goal is strictly text spacing for display, is to just define and use your own "tab":

```
public const string TEXT_TAB = "    ";

private void Province_Format(object sender, ListControlConvertEventArgs e)
{
    string provCode = ((Province)e.ListItem).ProvinceCode;
    string provName = ((Province)e.ListItem).ProvinceName;
    e.Value = provCode + TEXT_TAB + provName;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, works. However, the listbox area automatically collapses consecutive spaces to a single space. Needed to set the tab to be a series of magical `Alt+255` characters.

Comment: I tried it quick to verify and I didn't notice the collapsing. /shrug. Clever use of the invisible character.