# How to display combination of columns as display member?

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, edmx

I have the following code :

```
private void LoadCombos()
{
    //
    //Entity
    cmbEntity.ValueMember = "ID";
    cmbEntity.DisplayMember = "Name";
    cmbEntity.DataSource = store.Entities; //store is an objectContext
    //
}
```

I am trying to display Name as well as ID using this :

```
cmbEntity.DisplayMember = "ID+Name";
```

Is there a way by which I can achieve this, so as to display ID as well as name in combobox?

Comment: You can't do it like this way, you have to update the data in datasource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
cmbEntity.DataSource =
             store.Entities
                     .ToList()
                     .Select(e => new {Id = e.Id, Name = e.Id + e.Name});
```

or you can use

```
cmbEntity.DataSource =
     store.Entities
          .Select(e => new {Id = e.Id,
                     Name = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((decimal)e.Id + e.Name});
```

In this case you must add reference to assembly `System.Data.Entity.dll` and import namespace `System.Data.Objects.SqlClient`.

Comment: @PrakashVishwakarma Add `ToList()` to end. Did the combo populated when you use your code?

Comment: No combo is not populated with any data, tried ToList as well

Comment: Yes it populates data with my existing code which i have mentioned in my question cmbEntity.DataSource = store.Entities;

Comment: It gives error : Unable to cast the type 'System.Int64' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.

Comment: None of above works, even after the newly updated change by you.

Comment: What does it mean? You have error or the result is that not you expected.

Comment: The only issue is above code does not populate any data

Comment: Try to add `ToList()` to end of the query.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to this question is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006521/how-do-i-bind-a-combo-so-the-displaymember-is-concat-of-2-fields-of-source-datat) containing one of the ways you can achieve it using `Dictionary`

```
var dict = new Dictionary<Guid, string>();
foreach (var row in dt.Rows)
{
    dict.Add(row["GUID"], row["Name"] + " " + row["Surname"]);
}
cbo.DataSource = dict;
cbo.DataTextField = "Value";
cbo.DataValueField = "Key";
cbo.DataBind();
```

Comment: Combobox dowsn't have DataTextField and DatavalueField properties