# Multiple column combobox .NET with data binded from remote SQL Server

Tags: c#, .net, combobox

Is there anyway to have multiple columns in combobox with data binded from SQL Server?

```
+--------+--------+--------+
|id_equip|Descrip |Brand   |
+--------------------------+
|1       |20x20 TB|PVCCast |
|2       |20x20 TB|OtherB  |
+--------------------------+
```

The combobox holds a query like this. Value is `id_equip` and display is `Descrip`. Sometimes there is repetition from description column and I don't know what equipment I really am selecting. So brand column is the best way to destinct these repetitions.
I'm in C# .NET 4.5 env.

Comment: you can refer this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1006588/1196295).

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 this solved. I created a view and solved the issue. Thanks :)